# Vuetify bottom nav bar extension

Tags: css, svg, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am currently working on a little project and came up with a design for my bottom navigation bar (just a small personal project to learn).
[image]

Pretty standard bottom nav bar with two buttons left and then one reaching a little bit over.
First step was to to wrap my button into a div and push said div out. Next I wrapped that button in another div with a circle to create the „padding“. However, to create that „smooth“ curves from the bar to the padding was a challenge. I fiddled around with svg paths and was then able to put that svg together with the button into a div, push the svg out, then the button a bit.
However, I came across the fluid_bottom_nav_bar in flutter which seems to this flawless so I was thinking what better ways there are to achieve this.
Thanks guys.